# Why are some possessive pronoun not categorized as possessive adjectives?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, pronouns, possessives, predicate

In a book([Wren and Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wren_%26_Martin) updated Indian edition) I am reading it is said:

> The forms *my, our, your, her, their* are called **Possessive Adjectives** because they are used with nouns and do the work of Adjectives; as,
>
> This is *my* book.
>   Those are *your* books.
>   That is *her* book.

My understanding is that *my, your* and *her* can be replaced with adjectives in the above sentences as:

This is *the red* book.
These are *better* books.
That is *a small* book.

In the book I am reading, it further says *mine, yours, hers* are **possessive pronouns**, as used in following sense:

> This book is *mine*.
>   These books are *yours*.
>   That book is *hers*.
>   That idea of *yours* is excellent.

But my question is that *mine*, *yours*, *hers* are infact taking the position of **Predecative adjectives** as:

This book is *red*
These books are *better*
This book is *small*

So, can *mine*, *yours*, *hers* be considered as Possessive adjectives? If not then why?

Comment: No they can't. Just have a look at your own examples. Can you say _This is **mine** book_ or _these are **yours** books_, like you can with _my_ and _your_? Predicative use of a word is _not_ the same as an adjective.

Comment: @oerkelens I didn't think this way. So I take it as that for a _possessive pronoun_ to be classified as _possessive adjective_, it must be replaceable with adjective in both cases of _attributive adjective_ and _predicative adjective_

Comment: The dependent and independent gentives  are often analysed in trad grammar as 'possessive adjectives' and possessive pronouns respectively. But they are both genitive forms of the personal pronouns: "my" and "mine" are just as much pronouns as "me" and "I" are.

Comment: Even _nouns_ can be used attributively, so that doesn't mean much. If your conclusion is that possessive adjectives can be used as adjectives, then _theirs_ and _hers_ are not it :)

Comment: @oerkelens My book classifies _hers_ as _possessive pronoun_ (not possessive adjective). So I think all _possessive adjectives_ can be used as _adjectives_,

Comment: I am somewhat confused again. We can say _This is my(attributive adjective) book_ but can't say _This book is my(predicative adjective)_. So, _my_ can be used in place of _attributive adjective_, but not in place of _predicative adjective_. So _my_ can't replace adjectives in all cases. Does that mean _possessive adjective_ are only those words which replace _attributive adjective_? Don't they have any consideration to _predicative adjective_?

Comment: @user31782 My strong advice to you is to forget the term "possessive adjective". The dependent forms ("my, your, our, etc") and the independent equivalent forms ("mine, yours, ours etc") are all genitive (possessive) pronouns. Unlike adjectives, they don't function as modifiers but as determiners -- that is a crucial difference.

Comment: @user31782 We say "This book is mine", "mine" being the independent form. The NP "mine" is then subjective predicative complement of "be".

Comment: @user31782 You're never going to grasp this unless you forget ancient grammar. We have all told you that in today's grammar these words are pronouns. The dependent forms - the ones that require a following noun - like "my, your, our, etc", and the independent equivalent forms which can stand alone, like "mine, yours, ours etc" are all genitive (possessive) pronouns.

Answer (score 2):

Possessive-adjectives are not adjectives. Possessive pronouns are certainly not adjectives

Possessive-adjectives can function in some ways like adjectives (*my* book, *red* book). But they are can't form comparatives or superlatives (*a more my book, *the myest book). And they can't form a predicate (*this book is my.)

The possessive pronouns act like nouns. In modern English, they seem usually to appear in the predicate "It's mine!". In older forms of English they were seen in the subject (consider the Lord's Prayer: "For thine is the kingdom" thine is the old singular form of yours). Modern English seems to prefer "my one" in this position: "My one is better than yours."

Nouns and pronouns can appear as predicates. "It's a cat." "I want him." and so on. In the sentence "It's mine" the word mine is acting as a pronoun, not as an adjective. The word "mine" can't function as an adjective *"mine book" is incorrect.

It is best not to think of words like "my" as replacing adjectives. But instead, think of them as forming their own special class of words, which go before nouns to indicate possession.

Comment: They're certainly not adjectives, which is why it's unfortunate that out-of-date texts like Wren & Martin still use labels like *possessive adjective*.  Unfortunately, English grammar education is stuck in the stone age.

Comment: I am somewhat confused again. We can say This is my(attributive adjective) book but can't say This book is my(predicative adjective). So, my can be used in place of attributive adjective, but not in place of predicative adjective. So my can't replace adjectives in all cases. Does that mean possessive adjective are only those words which replace attributive adjective? Don't they have any consideration to predicative adjective?